# how to successfully install seaborn without error

Tags: python, seaborn

when i am running `import seaborn as sns` it throws me an error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cobyla: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import seaborn as sns

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cobyla: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated after comment by @mwaskom] You should fix yout SciPy installation:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall scipy
```

The command either installs the package if not existing, or re-installs and upgrade if it is not. The dependencies are not re-installed using the `--no-deps` flag.

Comment: This will not solve the problem; the `DLL load failed` implies a problem with compiled components but seaborn itself is pure Python so what actually needs to happen is a proper install of the relevant dependency (probably scipy).

Comment: pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall seaborn is not working.

Comment: Try with scipy as @mwaskom suggested (thanks for the feedback btw!): `pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall scipy`